# Manipulating a variable in a recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope

As an exercise I tried to to set a monster on fire with a little recursion. Works fine, however i would like to add extra damage with a button while the recursion is running. So far all functions setting a extra variable with a button did not work since i can't seem to find a way to influence the variable extra while the recursion is running. Basically in the below example i want a button press to do what currently the "if (monster === 55) ..." part of the code is doing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function print(text) { document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML += text + "\n"; }
        </script>
        <title>Monster</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="btnPoke" value="Poke it" onclick="" />
        <pre id="content"></pre>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var monster = 100;
            var extra = 10;

            function setonfire(monster, extra) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    print("Monster: " + monster + ", Extra: " + extra);
                    if (monster > 0) {
                        if (monster === 55) {
                            monster = monster - extra;
                            print("Poke for an extra " + extra);
                        }
                        monster = monster - 5;
                        setonfire(monster, extra);
                    }
                }, 200);
            }
            setonfire(monster, extra);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this is not too silly, but i am really at a loss and probably stuck inside a thought error. I would love any input that tells me where i got the concepts wrong. My suspicion is either scope problems or recursion

Comment: instead of monster==55, have a flag for extra damage (ie extraDamage=true) and check for it in the loop. In the button click set extraDamage=true when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with this method i can't get it to work. I set var extraDamage = false at the start of the setonfire function, checked in the loop for if (extraDamage === true) and wrote an onClick function doExtraDamage() { extraDamage = true; }. Still the loop itself while it is running is not interested in what i do with the button. Am i missing something?

Comment: I found it. The problem was that i initialized extraDamage within the function, which i shouldn't have. Setting it outside to false works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript passes primitives by value.  so when you call `setonfire(monster, extra);` you are passing the value of 100 to the method and it will never affect the outside `monster` variable.

You can reference the `monster` object directly in the method. So:

```
var monster = 100;
var extra = 10;

function setonfire(extra) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        print("Monster: " + monster + ", Extra: " + extra);
        if (monster > 0) {
            if (monster === 55) {
                monster = monster - extra;
                print("Poke for an extra " + extra);
            }
            monster = monster - 5;
            setonfire(extra);
        }
    }, 200);
}
setonfire(extra);
```

Otherwise make `monster` an object such as:

```
var monster = { health: 100 };
var extra = 10;

function setonfire(monster, extra) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        print("Monster: " + monster.health + ", Extra: " + extra);
        if (monster.health > 0) {
            if (monster.health === 55) {
                monster.health = monster.health - extra;
                print("Poke for an extra " + extra);
            }
            monster.health = monster.health - 5;
            setonfire(monster, extra);
        }
    }, 200);
}
setonfire(monster, extra);
```

**Edit:** Variable casing

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I thought by passing it directly i'd be super careful but instead got the opposite. The object method is what i will use in the future. But as with my answer to Hattan above, i still can only affect the health value after the loop is finished. Manipulating monster.health while the loop is running is still ignored :(

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jarga/8fzfq64g/ it is updating on every loop.

Comment: Sorry my language is probably still too layman like. The code in the fiddle is looking for the health of the monster to drop to 55 and then execute the extra substraction. What i am looking for is replace this fixed number check by a button press sometime while the loop is running. In plain english: while the monster is burning, i want to be able to hit it for extra damage whenever i decide to press the button (not precisely at 55. I tried this in the answer i gave to Hattan, but evaluating the button press to set something like extraDamage to true was just ignored by the loop.

Comment: Check the fiddle again, i updated it to do what you requested.  Just be sure to include your javascript functions in the `<head></head>` of your page so that the onclick handler will be able to see it.  Or use jQuery to late bind the click event.

Comment: I found it. I made an error with setting the variable to check for inside the function. It works now, thanks again.

Comment: #Just saw your fiddle# Now i see. Since it is now an object you wrote the function outside the loop and the monster health can now be affected. Understanding that was the root problem, i guess. I was checking it inside with the a bool. But yours is more elegant of course.